# multibib and links to bibliography (with hyperref, natbib)?

Tags: hyperref, natbib, links, multibib, subdividing

I'm using the [multibib package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/multibib.html) but cannot get links to work with it and [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/hyperref.html). Is this combination possible? A sample document follows:

If I add a `\usepackage{natbib}` in the preamble then links do work, but the custom labeling provided by multibib is removed. For example, without natbib the citations are [F3] and [B2] and no links. With natbib, citations are (3) and (2) and do link.

The [multibib documentation (PDF)](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/multibib.pdf) has a section (3) on how to handle packages which modify `\@citex`, but I am not sure how to use the information there to solve this problem.

```
% multibiblinktest.tex

\documentclass[10pt,letter]{article}

\usepackage[labeled,resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{F}{Foo}
\newcites{B}{Bar}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks = true,
  linkcolor=blue,   % color of internal links
  citecolor=blue,   % color of links to bibliography
  urlcolor=blue,    % color of external links
  pagebackref=true,
  implicit=false,
  bookmarks=true,
  bookmarksopen=true,
  pdfdisplaydoctitle=true
}

% \usepackage{natbib} % links work, citations not formatted by multibib...

\begin{document}

\nociteF{ref1}
\nociteF{ref2}
\nociteB{ref3}

A link to \citeF{ref4} and \citeB{ref5} goes here.

\bibliographystyleF{unsrt}
\bibliographyF{test.bib}

\bibliographystyleB{unsrt}
\bibliographyB{test.bib}

\end{document}
```

And the bibliography file:

```
% test.bib
@Article {ref1, author = Author1, title = Title1, year = 2010}
@Article {ref2, author = Author2, title = Title2, year = 2010}
@Article {ref3, author = Author3, title = Title3, year = 2010}
@Article {ref4, author = Author4, title = Title4, year = 2010}
@Article {ref5, author = Author5, title = Title5, year = 2010}
```

And to compile the document:

```
pdflatex multibiblinktest
pdflatex multibiblinktest
pdflatex multibiblinktest
bibtex F
bibtex B
pdflatex multibiblinktest
pdflatex multibiblinktest
pdflatex multibiblinktest
open multibiblinktest.pdf
```

Comment: I'm not setting multibib, hyperref, and natbib as requirements to solve this issue. A different package than multibib, if it provides the desired result, would be acceptable.

Comment: Is biblatex a possibility for you?

Comment: biblatex is a possibility. I have installed it. I have not found a simple tutorial on how to replace bibtex with biblatex, nor how to do something as complex as what I am trying to do with multibib...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is still lurking here to look for a solution like I was.

I managed to get the desired behavior using a combination of natbib and multibib commands and some spacing wizardry from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8834):

- `\citeF{}` makes sure that multibib to the correct citation. Otherwise there would be a question mark.
- `\cite[F][]{}` adds the letter F before the number as explained in the [natbib reference sheet](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/natnotes2.pdf)
- Combined, your citation should look like `\citeF[F][]{my_citation_2024}`.

Minimal example from the question. Don't forget to add the spacing hack in the preamble.

```latex
% multibiblinktest.tex

\documentclass[10pt,letter]{article}

% add natbib before multibib to get square brackets
\usepackage{natbib} 

% used to remove space between letter and number
\makeatletter
\def\NAT@spacechar{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks = true,
  linkcolor=blue,   % color of internal links
  citecolor=blue,   % color of links to bibliography
  urlcolor=blue,    % color of external links
  pagebackref=true,
  implicit=false,
  bookmarks=true,
  bookmarksopen=true,
  pdfdisplaydoctitle=true
}


\usepackage[labeled,resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{F}{Foo}
\newcites{B}{Bar}


\begin{document}

\nociteF{ref1}
\nociteF{ref2}
\nociteB{ref3}

% The formatting \citeF[F][] is the key 
A link to \cite[F][]{ref4} and \citeB[B][]{ref5} goes here.

\bibliographystyleF{unsrt}
\bibliographyF{test.bib}

\bibliographystyleB{unsrt}
\bibliographyB{test.bib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The only difference would be that the letters are not colored and linking as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a standard BibTeX style with `natbib`. You should be using the `unsrtnat` style rather than `unsrt` as you are using the `natbib` package.

Comment: That does not seem to have a positive effect on the issue. Links are created, but multibib labeling is now ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the line:

```
\usepackage[labeled,resetlabels]{multibib}
```

to

```
\usepackage[labeled]{multibib}
```

And it seems to work without natbib.

Make sure you keep multibib before hyperref!

Comment: I'm using TeXLive 2010 pretest..... I dunno if that mater.

Comment: The numbering is weird though. F1, F2, F3, B4, B5.....

Comment: Not a workable solution for me due to the numbering being messed up. 

Also, when I use the code I included above but remove the "resetlabels", I do not get links.

My version:
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.9-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.7)
kpathsea version 3.5.7
Copyright 2008 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).

Comment: I'm using texlive "0.20080816-3" installed via fink, which provides pdflatex version shown above.

Comment: Mine is pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.11-2.2 (TeX Live 2010) but I really have no clue which one of the bunch is the culprit.

Comment: OK I've upgraded to texlive 2010 pretest, and I get the behavior you describe, which is the same behavior I get with texlive 2008 (fink). I can get links with natbib, or without natbib (no "resetlabels"), but they aren't useful multibib-themed links.

Answer (score 0):

I use `multibib` and `hyperref`. I experienced that if I load `multibib` before `hyperref` the links of `\cite` are gone, but other links to pages, footnotes, images etc. stay. For me loading `hyperref` before `multibib` works.

Comment: Any chance you can supply a small example code?