# How to eliminate the space between multiple numeric citations when using citep and natbib?

Tags: natbib

I have a document that is using natbib via the following usepackage command:

```
\usepackage[numbers,square,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

When I cite multiple papers using the citep command, I get spaces between each of the numbers. For example, the following citation:

```
\cite{aldrich05,gudmundson01}
```

Gives me the following in-text output:

```
[5, 12]
```

However, I would like it to read:

```
[5,12]
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\NAT@def@citea{\def\@citea{\NAT@separator}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\makeatletter
\def\NAT@spacechar{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This actually works but has the side effect of making the citet command look funny.

Comment: Great!, this deletes the space between the author and year in `author-year` style which I needed :) .

Answer (score 0):

You can also decrease the space between multiple citations via a kern in `\setcitestyle`, e.g. `\setcitestyle{citesep={,\kern-0.1em}}`.