# eliminate the space between multiple numeric citations - bioinfo.cls

Tags: citing, natbib

I have a document that is using natbib via the following requirepackage command in [bioinfo.cls](http://arxmliv.kwarc.info/sty/bioinfo.cls) line 827.

`\RequirePackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}`

When I cite multiple papers using the cite command, I get spaces between each of the numbers. For example, the following citation:

`\cite{dinnes2007systematic,pai2009novel}`

Gives me the following in-text output:

`[3, 4]`
However, I would like it to read:

`[3,4]` 
Is there a way to accomplish this?

I tried this solution

> [How to eliminate the space between multiple numeric citations when using citep and natbib?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/how-to-eliminate-the-space-between-multiple-numeric-citations-when-using-citep-a)

But it does not work with bioinfo.cls. 
Any help would appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd like to have wrong output. The space after a comma is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\documentclass[numbers,sort@compress]{bioinfo}
\makeatletter
\def\NAT@def@citea{\def\@citea{\NAT@separator}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
...
\cite{dinnes2007systematic,pai2009novel}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{...}

\end{document}
```