# Why does hyperlink point to a wrong page when option "labeled" for multibib is activated?

Tags: hyperref, subdividing, multibib

When using `multibib` without `labeled` option, the hyperlink from citation sends me to correct page (page 2).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{z}{Bla}
\begin{document}

\section{Page}
\newpage
\citez{SOLAR}   
\subsection{Another subtitle}

\bibliographystylez{plain}
\bibliographyz{bib.bib}
\end{document}
```

When using with `labeled` option, the hyperlink from citation sends me always to page 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{z}{Bla}
\begin{document}

\section{Page}
\newpage
\citez{SOLAR}   
\subsection{Another subtitle}

\bibliographystylez{plain}
\bibliographyz{bib.bib}
\end{document}
```

Is there any idea?

Comment: Did you try deleting the `.aux` file and recompiling twice?

Comment: Looking at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2471/multibib-and-links-to-bibliography-with-hyperref-natbib/2474#2474) answer, did you try to load `multibib` *before* `hyperref`?

Comment: Loading hyperref before multibib is no good, then I get no links in citations at all (I've looked before at the provided link). And yes I'm deleting .aux files and even compiling 3 times :)

Comment: I was checking this, and find that there is a warning: `pdfTeX warning (dest): name{cite.SOLAR} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one`. Maybe this is the cause of the problem, somehow the cite is missing. However, I don't know where to look to solve this. Maybe someone else can point in the right direction.

Comment: This unfortunately seems to be a bug in `multibib` which doesn't seem to be maintained any more. The best thing to do is to switch to `biblatex`

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug of `multibib`. So you should write a bug-report. However I recommend the package biblatex which offers a more user friendly solutions. For more details have a look at the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)

A lot of possibilities can be found here at tex stackexchange:

- [sorting multiple bibliographies in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42192/sorting-multiple-bibliographies-in-biblatex)