# Biblatex equivalent to labeled multibib with working hyperref

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, hyperref, subdividing, multibib

I have a document using a labeled version of multibib, i.e. `\usepackage[labeled]{multibib}`. However, `hyperref` does not work on the cites and according to "[Why does hyperlink point to a wrong page when option “labeled” for multibib is activated?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19625/49645)", it seems one should use biblatex.

How can I achieve the same result as `\usepackage[labeled]{multibib}` using `biblatex` and have `hyperref` work correctly?

To be concrete, how can the minimal example document below be translated to biblatex?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labeled]{multibib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{A.bbl}
    \begin{thebibliography}{1}
        \bibitem{slam2001}
        Thomas Ball and Sriram~K. Rajamani.
        \newblock Automatically validating temporal safety properties of interfaces.
        \newblock In {\em Proceedings of the 8th International SPIN Workshop on Model
          Checking of Software}, 2001.
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{B.bbl}
    \begin{thebibliography}{1}
        \bibitem{blast2007}
        Dirk Beyer, Thomas~A. Henzinger, Ranjit Jhala, and Rupak Majumdar.
        \newblock The software model checker blast: Applications to software
          engineering.
        \newblock {\em International Journal on Software Tools for Technology
          Transfer}, 2007.
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{filecontents}

\newcites{A,B}{Primary,Secondary}

\begin{document}
CiteA~\citeA{slam2001}, CiteB~\citeB{blast2007}

\bibliographyA{refs}
\bibliographyB{refs}
\end{document}
```

The example produces the following using `pdflatex` where the `hyperref` does not work correctly on cites:

[image: Output from above tex document]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the following.

We will presume we have two `.bib` files: `\jobname-1.bib` and `\jobname-2.bib`, here created via `filecontents*`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-1.bib}
@inproceedings{slam2001,
  author    = {Thomas Ball and Sriram K. Rajamani},
  title     = {Automatically Validating Temporal Safety Properties of Interfaces},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 8th International SPIN Workshop on Model Checking of Software},
  editor    = {Matthew Dwyer},
  date      = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-2.bib}
@article{blast2007,
  author    = {Dirk Beyer and Thomas A. Henzinger and Ranjit Jhala and Rupak Majumdar},
  title     = {The software model checker {BLAST}},
  subtitle  = {Applications to software engineering},
  journal   = {International Journal on Software Tools for Technology Transfer},
  date      = {2007},
  volume    = {9},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\addbibresource{\jobname-1.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-2.bib}
```

These two files will be added to different keywords with Biber's sourcemapping

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-1.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, primary}, append]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-2.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, secondary}, append]
    }
  }
}
```

`\jobname-1.bib` gets the `keyword` `primary`, `\jobname-2.bib` gets `secondary`. (I chose `primary` and `secondary` here, but you can pick anything you like. Just make sure that these keywords are not used for anything else in your `.bib` file or in your bibliography setup.) Note that the names of the `.bib` files are 'hard-coded' in `\perdatasource`. If you have different files names, you need to adapt the code accordingly.

If you insist on continuous numbering (i.e. do not want the second bibliography to start at [B1]) we'll need to put an end to `biblatex`'s auto-detection of `resetnumbers` in case `labelprefix` is used:

```
\makeatletter
\providerobustcmd*{\blx@kv@defkey}{\define@key}

\blx@kv@defkey{blx@bib1}{noresetnumbersforlabelprefix}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\let\blx@saved@refcontext@labelprefix\blx@refcontext@labelprefix
     \let\blx@saved@refcontext@labelprefix\blx@refcontext@labelprefix@real
     \let\blx@refcontext@labelprefix\@empty
     \let\blx@refcontext@labelprefix@real\@empty}
    {}}

\blx@kv@defkey{blx@bib2}{noresetnumbersforlabelprefix}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\let\blx@refcontext@labelprefix\blx@saved@refcontext@labelprefix
     \let\blx@refcontext@labelprefix@real\blx@saved@refcontext@labelprefix}
    {}}
\makeatother
```

All the entries can be cited via `\cite` (so the `keyword` does not matter, there is not `\citeA` or `\citeB`).

The bibliography is printed with

```
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[keyword=primary, noresetnumbersforlabelprefix, title=Primary]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary, noresetnumbersforlabelprefix, title=Secondary]
```

That is the first bibliography only contains entries with the `keyword` `primary` (effectively that is entries from `\joabname-1.bib`), while the second contains `secondary` entries (`\jobname-2.bib`). I have added prefixes to the labels via the `labelprefix` option of `\newrefcontext` (that comes closer to your example).
The heading/title is controlled by the `title` option.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, defernumbers=true, backend=biber, maxnames=999]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-1.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, primary}, append]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-2.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, secondary}, append]
    }
  }
}

\makeatletter
\providerobustcmd*{\blx@kv@defkey}{\define@key}

\blx@kv@defkey{blx@bib1}{noresetnumbersforlabelprefix}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\let\blx@saved@refcontext@labelprefix\blx@refcontext@labelprefix
     \let\blx@saved@refcontext@labelprefix\blx@refcontext@labelprefix@real
     \let\blx@refcontext@labelprefix\@empty
     \let\blx@refcontext@labelprefix@real\@empty}
    {}}

\blx@kv@defkey{blx@bib2}{noresetnumbersforlabelprefix}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\let\blx@refcontext@labelprefix\blx@saved@refcontext@labelprefix
     \let\blx@refcontext@labelprefix@real\blx@saved@refcontext@labelprefix}
    {}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-1.bib}
@inproceedings{slam2001,
  author    = {Thomas Ball and Sriram K. Rajamani},
  title     = {Automatically Validating Temporal Safety Properties of Interfaces},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 8th International SPIN Workshop on Model Checking of Software},
  editor    = {Matthew Dwyer},
  date      = {2001},
}
@article{blast2008,
  author    = {Dirk Beyer and Thomas A. Henzinger and Ranjit Jhala and Rupak Majumdar},
  title     = {BLAST II},
  journal   = {International Journal on Software Tools for Technology Transfer},
  date      = {2008},
  volume    = {18},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-2.bib}
@article{blast2007,
  author    = {Dirk Beyer and Thomas A. Henzinger and Ranjit Jhala and Rupak Majumdar},
  title     = {The software model checker {BLAST}},
  subtitle  = {Applications to software engineering},
  journal   = {International Journal on Software Tools for Technology Transfer},
  date      = {2007},
  volume    = {9},
}
@inproceedings{slam2002,
  author    = {Thomas Ball and Sriram K. Rajamani},
  title     = {Interfaces are Cool!},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 8th International SPIN Workshop on Model Checking of Software},
  date      = {2002},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname-1.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-2.bib}

\begin{document}
CiteA~\cite{slam2001,slam2002}, CiteB~\cite{blast2007,blast2008}

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[keyword=primary, noresetnumbersforlabelprefix, title=Primary]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary, noresetnumbersforlabelprefix, title=Secondary]
\end{document}
```

[image: CiteA [A1, B3], CiteB [B4, A2]]

Hyperlinking seemed to work rather well here.

*edit* The answer was updated to work with more recent versions of `biblatex` (tested with v3.14, but it should work from v3.12 onward). If you are using an ancient version of `biblatex` (v3.3 or below), please refer to the edit history.

Comment: I now have your example working. However, is it possible to have Primary use numbers [1, ..., n] and Secondary [n+1, ..., m] like in the original example showint CiteA [A1] and CiteB [B2]?

Comment: @foens The `prefixnumbers` option implicitly calls `resetnumbers` (causing the numbering to start again from 1), maybe there is a workaround, I'm investigating.

Comment: @foens The updated answer shows a way to disable the implicit `resetnumbers=true`.

Comment: I couldn't get the updated version to work. Your MWE works fine, however, I wan't to save the bibliographies to primary.bib and secondary.bib, and then it blows up :) Anyways, thank you for your time, I can live with the numbers being a bid off.

Comment: @foens You have to replace all occurrences of `\jobname-1`(`.bib`) in the MWE by `primary`(`.bib`) and all of `\jobname-2`(`.bib`) by `secondary`(`.bib`). You furthermore cannot use the `keyword`s `primary` and `secondary` in any other context (if you want to, you need to replace every occurrence of `primary` and `secondary` above by other appropriate keywords).

Comment: @foens Could you be a bit more specific about what blows off, ideally with the error message/warning (or the expected output, in contrast to what you got)? What versions of `biblatex`/Biber are you using (it's version 2.8/1.8 here)? Have you tried an update?

Comment: I researched it a bit. It was a problem with TeXstudio and `filecontents` overwriting the `.bib` files each time. Building via the commands `pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex` everything works correctly. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @foens No worries. Note though that "in the wild" you would not use `filecontents`, you will just have the two files `\jobname-1.bib` and `\jobname-2.bib` (whatever their names be) in a place LaTeX can find them. (I'm not even sure you were implying that you use `filecontents` in your actual document, but better safe than sorry, I suppose).

Comment: If I run the MWE without the lines between `\makeatletter .. \makeatother` I still get continuous numbering....

Comment: @alexis Oh yeah. Thanks for pointing that out. Some internals changed that meant that the complete answer wasn't working as intended any more (and indeed the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` code does nothing in newer versions of `biblatex`). That should be fixed now, the code should once again produce the result from the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you @moewe. I think your comment "You furthermore cannot use the keywords primary and secondary in any other context" is so important that has to be in the answer too. I was all day fighting with apparently random zeros in my tex, and now figure out that mendeley (used to created the .bib) sometimes set the keywords field.

Comment: @moewe So now to avoid continuous numbering we just avoid the lines between `\makeatletter...\makeatother`? It is strange... some times it compiles like that, sometimes puts a lot of zeros.... not sure how to reproduce what I see. Also, is there a way to avoid the B label? (i.e. A0, A1, and then 1, 2, 3)... sorry for ask all this details.. not sure if is better to open a new question.

Comment: I found it!
`\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]`
`\printbibliography[keyword=primary, title=Primary]`
`\newrefcontext[]`
`\printbibliography[keyword=secondary, title=Secondary, resetnumbers=true] `

Comment: @alexis Yes. Usually when `labelprefix` is active, `biblatex` automatically resets the numbering of the bibliography entries in each new bibliography (see also my very first comment above). The code in `\makeatletter...\makeatother` was specifically put in to avoid that. Because the MWE uses `defernumbers` you will need an additional LaTeX run to get correctly numbered citations and bibliography entries. Sometimes when things go wrong or you experiment with many options and settings, `defernumbers` numbering can 'get stuck' with wrong numbers: possibly all zeros, possibly something more subtle

Comment: @alexis ... In those cases it helps to delete the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf` file and recompile. That shouldn't happen often. Instead of `\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A] \printbibliography[keyword=primary, title=Primary] \newrefcontext[] \printbibliography[keyword=secondary, title=Secondary, resetnumbers=true]` you could also say `\begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=A] \printbibliography[keyword=primary, title=Primary] \end{refcontext} \printbibliography[keyword=secondary, title=Secondary, resetnumbers=true]`. Which feels more natural will depend on your situation.