# Multiple bibliographies in biblatex without keyword

Tags: biblatex, biber, subdividing

I have read the questions: [biblatex: multiple bibliographies categorised by different .bib files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35279/biblatex-multiple-bibliographies-categorised-by-different-bib-files) and [sorting multiple bibliographies in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42192/sorting-multiple-bibliographies-in-biblatex), but although I profoundly respect all the work that has been done (notably by @PLK) to solve these questions, the provided solutions do no yet fully comply with my wishes.

I dream of a solution in biblatex/biber in which each .bib file would be treated independently (which would offer the maximum flexibility, in my opinion).
The syntax should rely on a single command, say \printbib, which would produce a single bibliography. Combining several bibliographies could be possible, using simple commands of the form

```
\printbib[Parameters1]{BibFile1.bib} 
...
\printbib[Parameters2]{BibFile2.bib} 
...
\printbib[Parameters2]{BibFile3.bib}
```

These commands should **not** rely on keywords (I would like to be totally free about the contents of my .bib files).
I understand that the syntax of biblatex using

```
\addbibresource{BibFile.bib}
```

in the preamble is really different, but is there any hope to realize my dreams?

P.S. By the way, this would also give a convenient way to reuse the .bib files produced by bibunits.

Comment: This isn't the place for feature requests, but I can't say I agree with your idea of what the default behaviour should be. More to the point, however, you can already use `Biber` to add keywords dynamically on a per `.bib` file basis (see command `\perdatasource`). Thus, you can give all entries of each file a unique keyword via `\DeclareSourcemap` and achieve your goal while nonetheless being 'totally free about the contents of [your] .bib files'.

Comment: Also: in order to facilitate answers, please provide a MWE example which includes at least two `.bib` files: no one wants to create everything anew just to answer someone else's question.

Comment: As jon said, you can automatically and dynamically add a keyword using Biber. See [Biblatex equivalent to labeled multibib with working hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171386/35864) and another example of `\predatasource` [BibLaTeX - The localization without a language key](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227460/35864).

Comment: Note that the approaches above doe the same as PLK did in [biblatex: multiple bibliographies categorised by different .bib files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864) but with the source-mapping from within the document, not via an extra file.

Comment: Would you be able to articulate your issue with a solution that uses in-document sourcemapping with `\perdatasource` to automatically add keywords to your different bib files so they can later be filtered (so you will not have to modify the keywords in the `.bib` file)? Or is that approach fine? This approach might not exactly be realisable as the one-line command you dream of, but in its effect it should be right up your street (from what I gather so far - if, however, you have further wishes than just producing split bibliographies, a more detailed question would help us understand those).

Comment: Did you have a look at the updated answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864)? I'm very much inclined to vote to close your question as a duplicate even though you said you looked at that question, because I think the in-document approach comes very close to what you want.

Comment: @moewe The simplest solution uses `refsection` (cf. p.78, biblatex manual) and is not documented by answers to other questions.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution uses `refsection` (cf. p.78, biblatex manual).

Ex:

```
\begin{refsection}[bibfile1.bib]
\nocite{*}  
\begin{refcontext}[... options ...]
\printbibliography 
\end{refcontext}
\end{refsection}
```

where `... options ...` is your particular options for this particular bib file.