# Is there a way to print the cited reference in my presentation from another file?

Tags: biblatex

> Is there any way  to refer the references cited (and only those cited,
>   not just any old entry in the .bib) in a another file with the same
>   labels (probably numeric) as in that file?

Currently, I am preparing my  presentation in beamer for one lecture. For that, I have a lecture notes in an `article` class.

T I am using `biblatex` for my reference.

I am having around 100 entries in my database bib file but only 20 are cited in  the lecture notes.

Now I want to give the reference in my presentation(at the last frame) which I have cited in my lecture notes.

Can I link my lecture notes to provide the reference here?

### Details:

The codes I have to used in my lecture notes to give separate reference is,

```
\printbibliography [title=Works cited,category=cited]
```

Like this if any command is there in beamer to give the reference?

I am expecting a code like,

```
\linkforbibliography{mylecturenotes.tex}
\printbibliography [title=Works cited,category=citedinthelink]
```

For the convinience, I am giving this mwe. I am using xelatex to compile this since I am using fontspec.

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[
    bullet=circle,      % Other option: square
    bigpagenumber,      % circled page number on lower right
    topline=true,           % colored bar at the top of the frame 
    shadow=false,           % Shading for beamer blocks
    watermark=BG_lower, % png file for the watermark
    ]{Flip}


\newcommand{\titleimage}{title}         % Custom title 
\newcommand{\tanedo}{tanedolight}       % Custom author name
\newcommand{\CMSSMDM}{CMSSMDMlight.png} % light background plot

\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries} % Frame titles should be bold

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\nocite{*}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{collection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{incollection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]


\begin{document}

\section{Title page}

\begin{frame}
This is my title page..
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Here my presentation contents are there...
Note that, nowhere in my presentation I am citing.
But, I need to give the reference at the last frame and that must be from some lecture notes(which has its own citations). The reference must the same as that of the lecture notes.
\end{frame}


\section{References}

\begin{frame}[c,allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
%        \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\checkmark}
%        \bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
%       {\scriptsize \bibliography{mybib.bib}}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

The flipbeamer template can be [found here.](http://www.lepp.cornell.edu/~pt267/docs.html)

### Alternate version of this question as suggested by moewe:

> Can I have a separate reference list which gives the reference given in the another file?

The following is my original file which is created recently.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=anyt,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\bibliography{mybib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}

    \begin{document}


    First reference is \cite{berman1974inverses}.. And the second reference is this \cite{lang2002algebra}. etc...

    But I want the reference list for this file as well as from the another file.


    \printbibliography[category=cited]
    \end{document}
```

Now, I want to give a reference list at the end in this file(say file1.tex), in which that is the reference list in my another file(say file2.tex).

### How to handle this situation?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand your problem. Especially the fourth and fifth paragraphs confuse me. With `\printbibliography [title=Works cited,category=cited]` you only get actually cited sources in the bibliography (assuming that the rest is set up correctly). Have a look at [Biblatex equivalent to labeled multibib with working hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171386/35864) and [Changing “Bibliography” title with biblatex - within the document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261443/35864) for examples on how to make all sources from a `.bib` file get one `keyword`.

Comment: I have cited in my lecture notes.  And I want my reference in my beamer file while I am taking class.  I want the same reference that of in the lecture notes@moewe

Comment: Does that mean you want to refer to references cited (and only those cited, not just any old entry in the `.bib`) in a another file with the same labels (probably numeric) as in that file? I don't think there is a `biblatex` solution out there for that at the moment, I think we had a question about this before.

Comment: exactly..the quesiton is that only@moewe

Comment: OK, maybe you can make that a bit clearer in your question, so people that know the answer (or have ideas for an answer) can find it easier. Don't get your hopes up too high, though. See this (complicated) non-`biblatex` solution [Use bibliography numbers and citation from other file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27243/35864), I'm not sure this is going to be easier with `biblatex`.

Comment: I think you could make your MWE much more minimal, for the general question it needn't even use `beamer`, just two short files would suffice. Though one could argue that the question doesn't require an MWE since the abstract idea is quite straightforward, I would urge you though to make the objective a bit more clear in the question. For me (I'm not a native speaker admittedly) it was quite hard to decipher what you want. For the question it doesn't really matter that you have a presentation and lecture notes, it is only important that you have two separate files.

Comment: @moewe exactly, I will try to make it more simpler..

Comment: when you ran bibtex on you `.bib` for your `lecture-note` it create `lecture-note.bbl` that will be included to `lecture-note.tex`  with `\printbibliography` you can use this file in your beamer

Answer (score 4):

This is `lecturenote.tex` file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib}
\begin{document}
bla bla \cite{mt} foo bar \cite{xyz}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is `presentation.tex` file

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
bla bla
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

run `pdflatex` + `bibtex` on `lecturenote.tex` as usuele this will create `lecturenote.bbl`
rename it to `presentation.bbl` and run pdflatex on `presentation.tex`

**Note:** no `\addbibresource` and no run of `bibtex` is needed for  `presentation.tex`

Comment: but its not working

Comment: it works fine for me. can you explain more what is the error?

Comment: actually no entry is coming in my slides except the black page for the reference...not even title...@touhami

Comment: @David see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/biblatex-submitting-to-a-journal

Answer (score 0):

Adding cites for the lecture only can happen, assuming you cite the origin of a comic that brightens the mood or a video that won't make it into the lecture notes, the following two alternatives allow to do this.

Assuming you use one large bib file for everything, the following non tex solution works. In your lecturenotes directory execute

```
find -iname '*aux' | xargs grep aux@cite | sed 's/.*cite{\(.*\)}/\1,/' > citedinlecturenotes.txt
```

which gives you a list of cited references in `citedinlecturenotes.txt`, which you can copy into a `\nocite{}` command in your beamer slides.
Normal `\cites{}` can then still be included everywhere.

As a fairly pure tex solution, you can use the brilliant tool bibexport to generate a new bib file with the name `citedinlecturenotes.bib` by running

```
bibexport -o citedinlecturenotes lecturenotes.aux
```

or

```
biber lecturenotes.bcf --output_format=bibtex
mv lecturenotes_biber.bib citedinlecturenotes.bib
```

within your lecturenotes directory.
biblatex can then include these references using

```
\begin{refsection}[citedinlecturenotes.bib]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
```

within your presentation.