# Netography for managing links

Tags: bibliographies, links

To manage my links used in my thesis, I wanted to use a netography so that I can cite links that are listed (with time stamp of the last visit!) at the end, like a bibliography. I couldn't find any package or similar questions. Does anyone know a package or a work-around?

Comment: It would depend on what you're using to generate your bibliography.  An option might be [here](http://timmurphy.org/2010/04/04/referencing-website-urls-with-latex-bibtex/)

Comment: Thanks, Scott, I use that now in conjunction with multibib. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2471/multibib-and-links-to-bibliography-with-hyperref-natbib

Answer (score 4):

You could use the glossaries package. It serves not only to make glossaries and acronyms, but also to make lists of things

The following should be put in the preamble after the hyperref package (if it is called, and I think you do call it)

```
\usepackage{hyperref} % Optional
...
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries} % toc option puts an entry in the table of contents
\newglossary{links}{sym}{sbl}{Netography}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{listofurls}
\begin{document}
...
```

The following should be put where you want the netography to appear

```
\glsaddall[types={links}] % This adds all of the defined acronyms without needing to call them in the body of the document
\printglossary[style=super,type=links,nonumberlist] % Prints the acronyms
```

Then, you create a file (named `listofurls` in this case) that contains the declarations as follows:

```
\newglossaryentry{url1}
{
    type=links,
    name={2012/10/10},
    sort=20121010, % Use what ever form you want to sort your list
    description={\url{www.google.com}}
}
\newglossaryentry{url2}
{
    type=links,
    name={2012/05/06},
    sort=20120506,  % Use what ever form you want to sort your list
    description={\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}}
}
```

Run `pdflatex jobname` then `makeglossaries jobname` then `pdflatex jobname`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Optional

\usepackage[toc]{glossaries} % toc option puts an entry in the table of contents
\newglossary{links}{sym}{sbl}{Netography}
\makeglossaries
%\loadglsentries{listofurls}

\newglossaryentry{url1}
{
    type=links,
    name={2012/10/10},
    sort=20121010, % Use what ever form you want to sort your list
    description={\url{www.google.com}}
}
\newglossaryentry{url2}
{
    type=links,
    name={2012/05/06},
    sort=20120506,  % Use what ever form you want to sort your list
    description={\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}}
}
\begin{document}

\glsaddall[types={links}] % This adds all of the defined acronyms without needing to call them in the body of the document
\printglossary[style=super,type=links,nonumberlist] 

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

**Update 1**

Oliver asks if you can reference the links in the body. Actually, there is a problem that I don't know how to handle with the `\url`command, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Optional

\usepackage[toc]{glossaries} % toc option puts an entry in the table of contents
\newglossary{links}{sym}{sbl}{Netography}
\makeglossaries
%\loadglsentries{listofurls}

\newglossaryentry{url1}
{
    type=links,
    name={2012/10/10},
    sort=20121010, % Use what ever form you want to sort your list
    description={\url{www.google.com}}
}
\newglossaryentry{url2}
{
    type=links,
    name={2012/05/06},
    sort=20120506,  % Use what ever form you want to sort your list
    description={\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}}
}
\begin{document}

For more information visit \glsdesc{url1}\footnote{This site was last visited in \gls{url1}} Notice that there is a problem with the url command...

Workaround \glslink{url1}{\url{www.google.com}}

\glsaddall[types={links}] % This adds all of the defined acronyms without needing to call them in the body of the document
\printglossary[style=super,type=links,nonumberlist] 
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Felipe! Is it possible to reference the links within the text of the document?

Comment: Bad news, there is a problem with the `\url`command. Normally you should be able to reference the link using `\glsdesc{url1}`. This should render `www.google.com`, but it renders url-www.google.com instead. A workaround is to use `\glslink{url1}{\url{www.google.com}}`